# XPath - How to compare string and sequence?

Tags: xml, xpath, compare, string-comparison, xpath-2.0

XML in short:

```
...
<team>
    <capitan>Zdeno Chara</capitan>
    <alernativeCapitan>
        <player>Zdeno Chara</player> <!-- NO Chara, he's the capitan obviously -->
        <player>Someone Else</player>
        <player>Someone Other</player>
    </alernativeCapitan>
</team>
<team>
    <capitan>Abc Edf</capitan>
    <alernativeCapitan>
       <player>Abc Xyz</player>
       <player>Bac Edf</player>
       <player>Abc 123</player>
    </alernativeCapitan>
</team>
...
```

Q: How to compare one string (capitan) with sequence (alternativeCapitan) in XPath?

I wold like to know if capitain is also written like a alternative capitan / player. Comparasion only in one team. (If so, its wrong. Thats all, doesnt matter if the result will be boolean or number.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not 100% clear for me, maybe you want something like this :

```
//team[capitan=alernativeCapitan/player]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/1968c313b899fb172593e4f3503acfde)</kbd>**

The above XPath will return all `team` where the `capitan` is also listed in the `alternativeCapitan` element. Or if you want the opposite, that is return all `team` where the `capitan` *is not* in the `alternativeCapitan` :

```
//team[not(capitan=alernativeCapitan/player)]
```

Comment: Hmm, how nicely simple. With boolean() perfect. I mostly tried horibble construction like - codepoint-equals and strings to codepoints ... and compare fuction. More than year I didnt see xpath :) Thx.